# PHP - Compare associative array with custom list and sort to match

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I need to sort an array in a particular order, sorting by the keys.  I know I need to do something like the below but have tried many different variations of the it and cannot get the result I need.

Can anyone help?

An example of the array is below and th results I am looking for for this would be:  Connectivity | Contact Centres | Cloud & Hosting | Business Continuity

> $solutions = Array ( [Business Continuity] => business-continuity
>   [Connectivity] => connectivity [Cloud & Hosting] => cloud-hosting
>   [Contact Centres] => contact-centres )

```
    function reorder_solutions($a, $b){
                    $custom = array('Lines & Calls', 'Mobile', 'Connectivity', 'Wifi', 'LAN', 'UC&C', 'Contact Centres', 'Cloud & Hosting', 'Managed Services', 'Security', 'Business Continuity');

                    foreach ($custom as $k => $v){
                        if ($k == $b) {
                            return 0;
                        }
                        return ($k < $b) ? -1 : 1;
                    }
                }

                uasort($solutions, "reorder_solutions");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
// loop over the $custom array
foreach ($custom as $key) {

    // add each key found in $solutions into a $sorted array
    // (they'll be added in custom order)
    if (isset($solutions[$key])) {
        $sorted[$key] = $solutions[$key];

        // remove the item from $solutions after adding it to $sorted
        unset($solutions[$key]);
    }
}

// merge the $sorted array with any remaining items in $solutions
$solutions = array_merge($sorted, $solutions);
```

Another way:

```
// create an array using the values of $custom as keys with all empty values
$custom = array_fill_keys($custom, null);

// merge that array with $solutions (same keys will be overwritten with values
//  from $solutions, then remove the empty values with array_filter
$solutions = array_filter(array_merge($custom, $solutions));
```

You can make it a one-liner if you like.

```
$solutions = array_filter(array_merge(array_fill_keys($custom, null), $solutions));
```

Comment: This seems to work although Im having issues where names with ampersands are not ordered correctly and are put at the end of the list...strange

Comment: That is strange. This tested okay for me using your values. Keys would only be put at the end of the array if they weren't found in `$custom` for some reason.